# Bash script to check the files based up on time

Tags: bash, shell

I have 3 regions like AWS, EMEA, APJ.  I use a script to get files into a common shared path:

- 3 files like a, b, c files at 3 am UST for AWS region;
- x, y, z files at 10 am UST for EMEA;
- 1,2,3,4,5 files at 11 pm UST for APJ region.

The files name won't change daily; it remains the same but the file name is not same from region to region and I need one script to check region wise whether all the files are there or not.  If the files are not there, it has to mail the missing file name.  It should come in single script and we are using [Tidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_Enterprise_Scheduler) to schedule the script.

Comment: What keeps you from using a list of "if file exists ... else mail name" ?

Comment: So, you collect 3 files from AWS, 3 files from EMEA, and 5 files from APJ?  Are the files removed after they're collected so you know whether the next day's files are new?  How do collect the files — `scp` or `sftp` or some other system?   Do you collect the files all at once, with a single invocation of the script, or at three different times?  If they're separate invocations, is there a parameter to tell you which region is to be processed this time?  How often do you change the list of files to be collected?  How often do you change the machines where the master files are found?

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] by making one or more scripts which simulate the behaviour of how and where the files are created?

Comment: 1) we had one script it will archive the files in different folder after files got processed and these files will be processed by some other system